# android webView loading finished but it was a blank only I touch the screen can the content show Idont know why?and how it happened

Tags: android, webview, touchscreen

when my webView load [this](http://hz139.com/3d/) page , it was blank-page or white page only I touch the screen the content can only show

```
    private WebView webview;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Context mContext;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    mContext = this;
    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    String url = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("url");
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    if(url!=null){
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "tips", "wate···the view is loading", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code..So that we can help you better.

Comment: Check whether you have flash player installed..I faced same problem before..

Comment: I use the phone default webBrower ,it is OK. so the problen must be in my code  but I dont known how to resove it

Comment: I am checking from my side and let you know the output.

Comment: I implemented the code.The problem is with url.I replaced your url with google.com and it worked fine.Can you please try with other url and let me know your output.Thanks

Comment: did you tried the link that I provided?

Comment: other url is OK ,I think the problem is with url,So I also try firefox and Chrome whith the same url but they all worked fine

Comment: I tried your site It worked fine,but it's not a full screen scene.it mean I should change the code of website right?

Comment: If you want i can provide the url with full screen.

Comment: Try this : http://www.tourwrist.com/direct_embed/51896

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is problem with url.
I tried with other url for 360 degree view and it worked.
Check this : [360 degree view](http://view360.in/virtualtour/gangaikondacholapuram/)

Comment: I agree with you ,but other browers use the same url and it can works well .what i should do with the code?

Comment: Android Default browser also shows white blank screen on Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working fine for me. Try it.

```
public class YourHtmlClass extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_containing_webview);
        mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings settings = mWebview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(AboutUsHtml.this, "", "Loading...",
                true);
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AboutUsHtml.this)
                        .create();
                alert.setTitle("No connection"));
                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setMessage("No connection"));
                alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        mWebview.loadUrl("Your URL Goes Here");
    }
}
```